# How to select ROI in binary threshold area using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, roi

I'm trying to crop the image from the binary image which is already processed from the original, suppose I have the original image

[image: Original Image]

and I got the binary image from the original

[image: Binary image]

and I want to crop the image only the white area using blob analysis

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you can use,

```
cv::Mat output_Mat = cv::Mat::zeros(RGB_Mat.size(), RGB_Mat.type());
RGB_Mat.copyTo(output_Mat, Binary_Mat);
```

Hope you can find corresponding python methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
points = cv2.findNonZero(binary_image);
min_rect = cv2.boundingRect(points);
```

Comment: cv2.boundingRect(binary_image) should work if you have the right Mat type